# Error when joinning two postgresql tables on WHERE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got two tables `A` and `B`

Let's say this is `A` :

| host_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jack |
| 3 | Lynn |
| 4 | Rose |
| 5 | Eva |
| 6 | Paul |

And this is `B` :

| id | host_id | geo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | 1,9,11 | ny |
| 254 | 1,12 | ny |
| 365 | 2,4 | nj |
| 4876 | 2 | bos |
| 554 | 2,1 | ny |
| 632 | 2 | bos |
| 136 | 3 | bos |
| 2543 | 4 | ny |
| 3432 | 4 | ny |
| 4432 | 8 | ny |
| 5432 | 6 | ny |
| 6765 | 7,8 | ny |

I'm trying to create a postgresql query that count the occurences of each `A.host_id` in `B` where `B.geo` is `ny`.

Expected output would be :

| host_id | name | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 3 |
| 2 | Jack | 1 |
| 4 | Rose | 2 |
| 6 | Paul | 1 |

This is my current query :

```
select 
A.host_id, 
A.host_names,
count(B.host_id) as count
from B
inner join A
on A.host_id :: varchar(255) like '%' + B.host_id :: varchar(255) + '%' 
where B.geo like '%ny%'
GROUP BY A.host_id, A.host_names
ORDER BY A.host_id;
```

However, I keep getting the following error message :

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: unknown + text
LINE 7: on B.host_id like '%' + A...
                                        ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: In Postgres the string concatenation operator is `||` not `+` . Read the docs [String operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html).

Comment: In general SQL, the concatenation operator uses `||`. Some DBMSs like SQL Server and MS Access supports `+` for strings but this  is not universal in SQL. Be sure to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) standard vs standard-plus methods and operators. Many Postgres features extends standard SQL!

Comment: Also you could probably replace with `select A.host_id = ANY(string_to_array ( B.host_id, ',')::int[]);`. Unless `B.host_id` is already an `int[]` then `select A.host_id = ANY(B.host_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to make sure your code is syntactically and logically correct:

```
on (',' || A.host_id :: varchar(255) || ',') like ('%,' || B.host_id :: varchar(255) || ',%')
```

I prepended and appended a comma at both sides so you will not get bad results, because

1 is not in 3,123,5

so we need to make sure that we try to search for exact values. And I used the correct concatenation of `||` as well.